# Name availability on Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

Is there a way to check if an app name is free/taken on the Google Play Store?
Searching on the play store for a given name gives me all the results with my name as a keyword.

Answer (score 9):

It doesnt matter, there can be multiple instances of the same name. It's the package name that cannot be duplicated... And as you are supossed to personalize your package name then your application name won't matter.

Comment: There are a few rules for app names on Google Play Store, namely, _"Apps must not have names or icons that appear confusingly similar to existing products, or to apps supplied with the device (such as Camera, Gallery or Messaging)."_

Reference: https://play.google.com/intl/en/about/developer-content-policy.html